# Grep files with numeric extension

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Consider a directory of 20 files numbered as follows:

```
ll *test*
> test.dat
> test.dat.1
> test.dat.2
...
> test.dat.20
```

A subset of the files that match to a given date can be found via

```
ll *test* | grep "Sep 29"
> test.dat
> test.dat.1
> test.dat.2
```

How can I search for a line pattern in *ONLY* this subset of files? I want to `grep` for the string `WARNING` in each line of the above three files.  How can I tell `grep` to limit its search to only this subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-l` option is made for that: list files that match

`-L` option does the opposite: list files that don't match

```
grep WARNING $(grep -l "Sep 29" *test.dat*)
```

#### EDIT

I misundrestood the question: you don't want to grep "WARNING" on files already containing "Sep 29", you want to grep "WARNING" on files last modified on Sep 29.

Therefore I suggest:

```
grep WARNING $(ll *test.dat* | grep "Sep 29")
```

But I wouldn't rely on `ll` output.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

`grep "WARNING" $(ll *test* | grep "Sep 29")`

That way, the output of your command will become the `<files_to_search_in>` argument of your outer-most `grep` command.

Keep in mind that since you are using `ll` in your original command, the output of it will give you not only the file names you want, but other file details (permissions, date, etc). You might have to do further processing in your "inner" `grep`, so that the information passed to the outer-most `grep` command will be limited to file names.

While at it, **consider doing your file filtering in your inner-most subshell with the `find` command** ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)) instead of a combination of `ll` + `grep`: use the right tool for the job (:

Comment: Thanks, I'll try `find`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
find . -type f -name "test.dat*" -newermt 2017-09-29 ! -newermt 2017-09-30 -exec grep WARNING {} \;
```

**Details**

`-type f`: searching file only

`-name "test.dat*"`: only file beginning by "test.dat"

`-newermt 2017-09-29 ! -newermt 2017-09-30`: only file with modification date = 29 Spetember 2017

`-exec grep WARNING {} \;`: each time a file is found, execute `grep WARNING` on it

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following `find: invalid predicate `-newermt'`

Comment: Unfortunately your `find` doesn't seem to support `-newermt` :(

Comment: Then maybe look for `-mtime` instead. You will have to do some calculations but it's certainly doable (and probably has been asked here a number of times before, so you could just google).